# SMTP Email is not working on Joomla

Tags: php, smtp, joomla3.0

I am using joomla 3.2.0 and configured SMTP email account details in the Global configuration to send an email. I am using Joomla com_contact  as a contact form. when I fill the data and submit the form, the email is not triggered.

We are facing this issue in  live environemnt. But in staging server is working fine. Both server a re Linux server with CENT OS.

In the live server , I have printed error of email send method below.  Please suggest what is the issue ?

### Error

```
JException Object
(
[level:protected] => 8
[code:protected] => 500
[message:protected] => SMTP connect failed
[info:protected] => 
[file:protected] => /var/www/html/mywebsite/libraries/legacy/error/error.php
[line:protected] => 178
[function:protected] => 
[class:protected] => 
[type:protected] => 
[args:protected] => Array

 (
    )
```

SMTP account configuration for live and staging server are same. But I am facing an issue in live server only. Can anyone suggest what is the issue ?

Comment: Does joomla has its own mail class for sending emails, or it is using 3rd party libraries like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer? I'm pretty sure some kind of ecommerce cms' s like prestashop using SwiftMailer to handle the emailing.

Comment: Btw your issue is about can not connect smtp server. Can you please share some codes and smtp parameters, because we are not mind readers.